# When running images/containers on Docker Desktop keeps giving me error /usr/app/node_modules/.bin/../node/bin/node: 1: This: not found

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, mern

I am trying to Dockerize a MERN Stack on VSCode in Windows 11 using Docker Desktop. The docker-compose builds the backend, frontend, and mongodb images correctly. However, whenever I try to run the frontend and backend images on Docker Desktop, it keeps exiting with code 127. My guess is the node version I am using in the Dockerfile, but I've tried with node:latest and node:21. The error it is throwing is /usr/app/node_modules/.bin/../node/bin/node: 1: This: not found.

Dockerfile for frontend:
[My current frontend Dockerfile is using node:latest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXxQz.png)

Dockerfile for server:
[server Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL9gw.png)

docker-compose.yml:
[docker-compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/495Ex.png)

Results on Docker Desktop: [output on Docker Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C79wR.png)

My package.json folders are using the latest version of node (21.x.x)

Was trying to run the MERN Stack in the Docker images.